# Base Class Form Method Accessing Derived Forms Controls

Tags: c#

I have a project that uses MANY dialogs. Each dialog performs much of the same code and business policies are an issue. For this reason I have created a method that accesses the controls on the form.

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
```

I need to access the controls on of the DERIVED Form, as these controls change. I want to do so by calling the base class method. Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "controls of the derived form"? That's not very clear. If you can post some more code, that would help.

Comment: does the code not make clear by what i mean by controls? Oops sent that too soon. Textboxs mostly. Grr, not use to "enter" = sumit in textarea controls. Sorry.

Comment: If it did, do you really think he would need clarification?

Comment: // Stripped Down Code
        protected void PopulateContols()
        {
            foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
            {
                if (control.Tag != null)
                {

                    control.Text = "foo";
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @GeekDrool: What does "by calling the base class method" mean, and how does it relate to the second code sample you posted?

Comment: Why don't you post the code for your `Form` subclass? We might then  be able to understand what the real issue is..

Comment: Do you get points or something for just asking me questions? Cause this feel like the twilight zone here.
I am sorry, I am new to the community here but i did not realize i needed to explain basic C# constructs in order to get help. “How do I drive to the store in my car” Reply “What does dive mean and can you explain what a car is”

Comment: @GeekDrool - we're just here to help. More information is always better in solving a problem, and with your attitude your likely to get any. +1 vote to close.

Comment: Take care, will go back to regular old community of actual coders who understand what “base”, “class” , “Derived” “Method”, and “Control” means. - Dear god, i did tag this C#

Comment: I don’t know what the construct here are for the community, but, I’m guessing that "asking" gives points? as in ANYTHNG, even if its..... Nevermind, im blown awayy

Comment: @GeekDrool: No, I don't get any "points" for asking you questions. Your question *does* indeed appear to be about "basic C# constructs" as you call it. Unfortunately, the question is a little too vague for my understanding to answer as is, so I do think my questions are legitimate. Of course, if you think there's enough clarity in your question that my queries are 'basic', you don't need to answer them. Cheers.

Comment: Just for the record, "Base Class Form Method Accessing Derived Forms Controls" really honestly explains is ALL, all by itself to a coder. What the hell just happened, here, is beyond me.

Comment: Base Class Form <- Check? Method <- Check? Accessing <- Implies Scope, Derived Forms Controls - Mind Blowing, why ask me all those questions if those things are beyond your scope, if that was complicated, why waste my time?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to traverse the control structure of an extended class using a method declared in the super class?

[Every container control on the page, and the page itself, has a Controls collection that you can use to get to individual controls.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4(v=VS.80).aspx)

This might give you the help you need [C#, recursively notify child controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418018/c-recursively-notify-child-controls)

Comment: Thank you sir you are definitely on the right track this is what my method does.  The problem is I then take this Windows Form and create a derived (Inherited form).  Then add controls to that new form.  When the method in the base class is called from the derived (inherited) form, the base class is not seeing the inherited form’s controls as the inherited form is a new class onto itself.  What is the method for accessing the derived forms controls.

Comment: @GeekDrool If you've inherited from the base class then all the properties and methods it has should exist in the instance of your derived class. Can you post any more code, particularly where you declare your inherited class? There should be no parent/child relationship.